# How to add an additional procedure parameter to a c# tableadapter update method?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameters, binding, tableadapter

I have a Winforms app in C# that uses a dataset's tableadapter fill and update methods to call stored procedures in the SQL Server database. This is working fine. All parameters to the update stored procedure are mapped to existing columns in the datatable.

Now I want to add an additional parameter to the update stored procedure and method. But this column is not sourced from the datatable, but is sourced from another control on the form. It's a simple date that is picked from a calendar just once, and is not set row by row in the grid.

So I added a new parameter to the stored procedure, but without mapping it to a column in the dataset. When I did this, and reconfigured the tableadapter, I got the error:

> Some parameter bindings are missing. Values from the DataSet will not be used for those parameters.

I would hope and expect that the tableadapter update method would then be able to accept in this additional parameter as a method argument, but it doesn't.

How should I approach this?  Is there a way to override the update method to provide this value?  Or should I add a "synthetic" column to the dataset, which gets set for each row (with the one value) at update time?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following VB code works for me:

```
Me.MyTabTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IntParam", 5)
Me.MyTabTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TabParam", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = tempDataTable   
Me.MyTabTableAdapter.Update(MyDataSet.MyTab)
```

`MyTabTableAdapter` is a table adapter corresponding to `MyDataSet.MyTab` table.

Param `@TabParam` is a param of user table type. I was able to create a `DataTable` in my code on a fly and pass it to the server side. Column order of `tempDataTable` must exactly match those defined in the user table type.

NB my first attempt was to use the "synthetic" column to the dataset as you have suggested. It has not worked. It is not possible to bind such column to the stored procedure param.

**UPDATE**
The above code works but.... just once.
I have not taken into account that every save attempt will add another param with the same name which causes crash.
At the moment I believe that best approach is to add the proper param to `MyTabTableAdapter` with mouse in MyDataSet.xsd design mode and simply set:

```
Me.MyTabTableAdapter.Adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters("@TabParam").Value = tempDataTable
```

This is VB code so () meains indexing :).